# Truncate ''space'' issue x/002

Tags: python, integer

```
import re
with open("./teste/counter.txt", "r+") as count:
    countread = count.read()

        inputvar = input("Counting - write anything: ")
    if countread == "":
        print("Countread is ''None''. Adding to text file number ''1''.")
        count.write('1')
    else:
        count.truncate(0)
        countread = countread.replace(' ', '')
        countplus = int(countread) + 1
        print(countread)
        count.write(str(countplus))

    count.close()
```

I am trying to erase the file with count.truncate(0) but after it adds 1, and goes to 2 in my text file, at 3 I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x002'
```

For the line ''countplus = ...''

EDIT: By the way the ''countread replace'' was a try to fix this issue.

Comment: I think you need a `seek` after the `truncate`.

Comment: What is `countread`? And you never use `inputvar`.

Comment: What is `countread`?  You haven't shown us what that variable is.

Comment: edited it. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this

```py
while 3>2:
    with open("./teste/counter.txt", "r+") as count:
        countread = count.read()
        if countread == "":
            countread = "0"
        inputvar = input("Counting " + countread + " write anything: ")
        if countread == "0":
            count.write('1')
        else:
            countplus = int(countread) + 1
            count.truncate(0)
            count.seek(0)
            countread = count.read()
            count.write(str(countplus))

    count.close()
```